# How do I modify this wpdb query to include posts that have a post_status of publish and draft?

Tags: wpdb, post-status

I'm using the following function to count the number of posts an author has made from a custom post type.

```
<?php
function count_user_posts_by_type($userid, $post_type) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql($post_type, TRUE, $userid);
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );
    return apply_filters('get_usernumposts', $count, $userid);
}
?>
```

To echo out the count I use

```
<?php echo count_user_posts_by_type(wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'custom_post_type_name'); ?>
```

From my testing it seems to count just the posts that have a `post_status` of `publish`. How can I modify the function so it also counts posts that are `draft` ?

I've tried to modify the query as follows but it seems to have no effect whatsoever:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where AND post_status IN ('publish','draft')" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AND` and `OR` statements in MySQL. Try this:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'draft')" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT COUNT(*)  
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'draft' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Just modify the query to retrieve the posts for the current user.